# move_uploaded_file not working in the environment?

Tags: php, mysql, sunos

I am pretty sure that all my function are working since I test it on my local computer.

But for some reason, it doesn't work on prod server.

Is there any other way to upload the image? or if its possible I can test it on prod server?

PS: I have really limited permission on prod server, its just like a Hosting with SSH access only. can't do anything and for some reason we have to use this server not change to some other one.

Comment: Does your script have write permissions on the folder you are moving the uploaded file to?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have proper write permissions on the folder where you are uploading files...

Comment: Dude... you pretty much copied the same thing that Ali posted in comments 1h 45m previous to your post.

Comment: Well, I have right permissions for www folder but i do not think i have permission to access /var/tmp/ folder. Thats problem

Comment: Anil, your 'answer' should better be posted as 'comment'